# Javascript For Loops Body Syntax

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working with the following code:

```
var topics = ["Basketball", "Baseball", "Football", "Hockey", "Golf", "Tennis"]
for (i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    //???
}
```

How can I write code in the body of the for loop to create a button for every item in my array as it goes through my topics variable?

Comment: This is not a question about "syntax". It's a question about "how do I write code to do something".  The word "syntax" is essentially the same as the word "grammar".

Comment: Can you post samples of what you've tried, and any particular issues you may have?  SO is unfortunately not a codewriting service.  Specific questions we're more than happy to help with :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```js
var topics = ["Basketball", "Baseball", "Football", "Hockey", "Golf", "Tennis"]
for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById('board').innerHTML+="<input type=button value="+topics[i]+" ><br>";

}
```

```html
<div id="board" ></div>
```